# An error occurs while converting the doc, ppt, and xls files to pdf using Java Open Office

Tags: java, openoffice.org

The code currently in use normally converts the doc, ppt file to a pdf file, but there is an error in the xls file. What is the reason? And is the docx, pptx, and xlsx files impossible?

```
    OpenOfficeConnection OOconnection = new SocketOpenOfficeConnection(8100);
    OOconnection.connect();

    String file = "C:\\test.xls"; //<--- insert file


    String new_file_name = null;
    new_file_name = file.substring(0, file.indexOf(".")) + ".pdf";


    File inFile = new File(file);
    File outFile = new File(new_file_name);

    // the conversion
    DocumentConverter PDFconverter = new OpenOfficeDocumentConverter(OOconnection);
    PDFconverter.convert(inFile, outFile);
    OOconnection.disconnect();
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.connection.OpenOfficeException: conversion failed: could not load input document
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.loadAndExport(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:134)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convertInternal(OpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:120)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:104)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:74)
    at com.artofsolving.jodconverter.openoffice.converter.AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.convert(AbstractOpenOfficeDocumentConverter.java:70)
    at org.test.ChangeOffice.App.main(App.java:56)
```